# Rails - how to use ActionDispatch::Integration::Session in ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob, actiondispatch

In Rails' console `app` is defined as

```
[1] pry(main)> app
=> #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x000000189028e8
```

Now, I have a simple job like:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :low

  def perform
    app.get('/my/path', nil, {'Accept-Language' => "it"})
  end
end
```

If I call `MyJob.perform_now` I get

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `app' for

How can I use `app` in a Rails' ActiveJob?

Comment: What will be a goal of such job? It looks very weird... I take into account a possibility, that you move in wrong direction

Comment: are you just trying to get a rendered response of the page? to Save it to a static file or something? If you are on rails 5 there is easier way to do it than using a app.get

Comment: I need to call a controller's method, basically to trigger some cache-related-stuffs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :low

  def perform
    app = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
    app.get('/my/path', nil, {'Accept-Language' => "it"})
  end
end
```